# I Want create XML File Using Asp.net MVC And need to add <media:tagname> while creating Tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc

i am using c# to create the xml file i used the technique  the code given below but it does not add media: before the tag name and i need to create it like `<media:tagname>.`the result file have only tag named `<description>`

```
XmlElement age = writer.CreateElement("media:description");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want 'media' to be your XML namespace , you can do this:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement age = document .CreateElement("media","description","http://yourmedianamespace");
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp for more on namespaces.